# Two additional tests of Joseph in Talmud?

Tags: talmud-gemara, yosef, test

This [discussion](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1355560/jewish/Daily-Zohar-Miketz-Day-1.htm) mentions that besides the test with Zuleica/Zuleicha (Potiphar's wife, according to the reference 166 [Book of Yasher](https://archive.org/details/cu31924088174754) cited on p.371 in this Midrash [book](http://www.judaica.com/the-midrash-says-1-beraishis-genesis-the-book-of-beraishis-hard.html)), there were two even more severe tests mentioned in the Talmud

> Joseph is the only one referred to as HaTzadik/the righteous one. His
>   life mirrors the actions of the Supernal Foundation, whose role in the
>   "downward" progression of G-d's flow is to bring blessing and bounty
>   to the lower world. He was severely tested [the Talmud brings 2
>   examples of even greater testing], and passed.

Would someone kindly point me towards a descriptions of those tests (preferably with an English translation)?

Comment: Why was the miketz tag removed? Also Aaron, can you give me a source for Zuleica stories from the Kurdish Jews?

Comment: It's in [Sanhedrin](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%91)